# Using std::string_view with api that expects null-terminated string

Tags: c++, string, c++17, null-terminated, string-view

I have a method that takes `std::string_view` and uses function, which takes null terminated string as parameter. For example:

```
void stringFunc(std::experimental::string_view str) {
    some_c_library_func(/* Expects null terminated string */);
}
```

The question is, what is the proper way to handle this situation? Is `str.to_string().c_str()` the only option? And I really want to use `std::string_view` in this method, because I pass different types of strings in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot alter a string through `std::string_view`. Therefore you cannot add a terminating `'\0'` character. Hence you need to copy the string somewhere else to add a `'\0'`-terminator. You could avoid heap allocations by putting the string on the stack, if it's short enough. If you know, that the `std::string_view` is part of a null-terminated string, then you may check, if the character past the end is a `'\0'` character and avoid the copy in that case. Other than that, I don't see much more room for optimizations.

Comment: nice use for VLA.

Comment: @user1095108 but any compiler that allows VLAs in C++ is applying a non-Standard extension, so I would say VLAs can never be nice. :P

Comment: They are practically supported everywhere through alloca, you can make them portable

Answer (score 30):

I solved this problem by creating an alternate `string_view` class called `zstring_view`. It's privately inherited from `string_view` and contains much of its interface.

The principal difference is that `zstring_view` cannot be created from a `string_view`. Also, any `string_view` APIs that would remove elements from the end are not part of the interface or they return a `string_view` instead of a `zstring_view`.

They can be created from any NUL-terminated string source: `std::string` and so forth. I even created special user-defined literal suffixes for them: `_zsv`.

The idea being that, so long as you don't put a non-NUL-terminated string into `zstring_view` manually, all `zstring_view`s should be NUL-terminated. Like `std::string`, the NUL character is not part of the size of the string, but it is *there*.

I find it very useful for dealing with C interfacing.

Comment: I just did the same, and I agree the interface is very nice and removes the last reason for ever doing const std::string& as a parameter. You do lose a lot of convenience using the private inheritance (like comparison, and conversion back to string_view) - looking at the interface, it seems the only problematic mutators are remove_***fix and swap - I just reimplemented swap, and added remove_***fix as private non-implemented members, and everything seems to work fine - so you can indeed publicly inherit from std::string_view. Only issue is new mutators added to string_view in the future.

Comment: Although it could be said it is bad style. And additionally, you would have issues with passing zstring_views to functions taking string_view& (which is weird in more than two ways...)

Comment: @Shaggi `zstring_view` is pretty safe to allow to decay to `string_view` implicitly, for convenience. It's the reverse order that needs to be guarded against.

Comment: Agree, but if you're deriving publicly, no conversion happens when passing a zstring_view to a function taking string_view&, making it unsafe.

Comment: This is my attempt at implementing `zstring_view`. Any feedback would be appreciated. https://gist.github.com/tuket/d4c09344a2173b1acc1651d416733fbd

Answer (score 6):

You certainly shouldn't call `data` on `std::experimental::string_view`:

> Unlike basic_string::data() and string literals, data() may return a
>   pointer to a buffer that is not null-terminated.

So call `to_string` and `c_str` on that:

```
void stringFunc(std::experimental::string_view str) {
    some_c_library_func(str.to_string().c_str());
}
```

or:

```
void stringFunc(std::experimental::string_view str) {
    std::string real_str(str);
    some_c_library_func(real_str.c_str());
}
```

Comment: string::data() returns a pointer to just the raw character string, which is NOT necessarily null-terminated. If you want a null-terminated string, use string::c_str()

Comment: @HowardLeeHarkness since C++11, it *is* necessarily null-terminated. See e.g. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/

Answer (score 0):

In some cases C-stype functions have overloads, which accept the length of string as a separate argument.

E.g. instead of using `strcasesmp()` it worth to switch to `strncasecmp()`.
For sure, in this particular case, it would require additional logic implemented in case when strings are not equal, but the first n characters are equal.

But it could be good alternative to writing custom class for string views.