# How does one deal with different types when using custom allocated strings?

Tags: c++, string, allocator

I have started experimenting using custom allocators with `std::basic_string` in a video game project. This is my first time dealing with custom allocators, so I'm learning a lot.

But the problem is, I would like to be able to call any function taking a "string" parameter with any `std::basic_string` (`std::string`, `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, custom_allocator<char>`, etc.).

However, providing a custom allocator "changes" the type of `std::basic_string` (I mean, it differs from `std::string` that I've been using).

So I thought of different solutions:

- Use template programming in functions to take a `T` instead... but using templates everywhere seems a bit tedious and overkill...
- Switch to C-style strings everywhere, and provide `my_string.c_str()`, which seems like a very bad idea, considering the loss of C++ features.
- Implement my own `String` base class and make all the `CustomAllocatedString` inherit from it. This is for a personal project, so I don't mind experimenting, but I know that implementing my own "STL" can be very time consuming (among other things).
- During my research, I learned about polymorphic allocators and `std::pmr::string` (I use C++ 17). Although this seems to include memory overhead (plus the indirection), it's really interesting.
- Am I missing something really obvious here?

What do you think about this? Or is mixing different allocation methods with a single type a really bad idea in the end?

Answer (score 2):

The solution might be to use `string_view` instead; that way functions don't have to deal with how strings are allocated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

void foo(const std::string_view str) 
{ 
    std::cout << str; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "Hello";
    std::pmr::string s2 = "World";
    foo(s);
    foo(" ");
    foo(s2);
    foo("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about using `string_view` but, in my project, I have to call some C code sometimes, which seems to be a little bit tedious considering a `string_view` can be trimmed beforehand without modifying its inner string.

Comment: @cloudstrife7001 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288372/10147399

Comment: This solution is really interesting!