# Does a string_view that lazily calculates size during construction comply with C++standards other than complexity requirements

Tags: c++

Specifically, when using char * to construct a string_view, there will be a linear complexity in the size construction process. My idea is that if size is set to a specific value and then calculated when using certain interfaces like size(), it should be possible to handle some unnecessary performance losses. Can this designed string_view equivalently replace the C++standard string_view without generating errors?

Comment: Where is the advantage? If you try to do it lazily, you need an `if (!calculated) compute_now();` everywhere the size is needed. I bet that will make everything slower, and be a net loss.

Comment: @BoP: It won't _necessarily_ be a loss (and it will never be a huge loss). If most instances never invoke the `size()` function, it might even be a slight gain. But I agree that it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: The buffer used to initialize the `string_view` could be modified later, but the `size()` must be the position of the null terminator at the time of construction. `char buffer[2] = "a"; std::string_view view(buffer); buffer[0] = 0;` The `view.size()` is required to be 1, but if you calculated it lazily, it would be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Complexity guarantees are not easily detectable. As such, there won't be any "errors" for violating them. But since people write their code with respect to such guarantees, the mostly likely result will be that people will get degraded performance relative to what they expect.

And no, lazily evaluating `size()` would *not* comply with the complexity guarantee. It is an O(1) size, not an amortized O(1) size. That means it always has to be O(1).

Besides, the only advantage of lazy evaluation in this case is the possibility that nobody ever checks the size (if they do, they'll incur the penalty). It'd be much more reasonable to just have an unsized `string_view`-like type, with no `size` member. It could still be a contiguous range, just not a *sized* contiguous range (as the `end` would be a sentinel, not an iterator). The size can be computed as needed, but everyone would know that it would be a slow computation and therefore should be avoided. Explicitly disallowing a thing rather than implicitly allowing it but making it slow is always preferable.

Such a [specific string view type (one that knows that it is NUL-terminated) is useful to have as a *distinct type* from `string_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286898/using-stdstring-view-with-api-that-expects-null-terminated-string/41288372#41288372). That is, don't try to replace `string_view` with it.